# React-Native App Error "Attempt to invoke virtual Method"

Tags: android-studio, react-native

[image: Emulator Error]

I get this error when I try to run my App. 
There are no errors in Android Studio,Server and on running react-native run-android.
Unable to fix this. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an Android error, could you check what library/plugin that you are using is causing this? Seems like some Facebook plugin/library